# Differentation from first principles - apparent division by zero?

Tags: derivatives

[image]

how come its okay to let $\delta x$ equal $0$ without making the left hand side $\delta y/\delta x$ impossible, wouldn't you final statement be $\delta y/0 = 3x^2 - 2$?

Comment: Well, the perks of using infinitesimal calculus...

Comment: We're not letting $\delta x$ equal zero, we let it tend towards zero. We look at $$\lim_{\substack{\delta x \to 0 \\ \delta x \neq 0}} \frac{\delta y}{\delta x}.$$

Comment: The title mentions integration, but the body of the Question concerns differentiation rather than integration.

Comment: dammit, can i change the questions name?

Comment: and thank you makes sense now

Comment: You should check out 1brown3blue's youtube series entitled "the essence of calculus" on youtube. He has a very good discussion on small, but finite changes in the context of analysis.

Comment: You can change the title by hitting the "edit" button at the bottom of the question.

Comment: okay its edited, and will do

Comment: Note that $\delta y$ and $\delta x$ are linked. So as $\delta x$ becomes small, so does $\delta y$. In fact, for nice enough functions they're almost proportional when they're small enough. That "proportionality" constant is the derivative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we compute $\lim_{x\to x_0}f (x) $

in fact we should write $$\lim_{x\to x_0 x\ne x_0}f (x) $$

we do not need the value of $f (x_0) $.
for example

$$\lim_{x\to 0 x\ne 0}\frac {\sin (x)}{x}=1$$

we only need it when we look for continuity at $x_0$.